# Share a resource image with intents

Tags: android, android-intent, android-resources, android-sharing

I'm trying to share an `image/jpg` stored in the `raw` resource folder of my application, but the `Intent` seems not to find the image resource and sends nothing.

Here is my code for sending (*in Kotlin*):

```
val current = filePaths!![mViewPager!!.currentItem]
val uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + current.resourceId)
val shareIntent : Intent = Intent()
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
shareIntent.setType("image/*")
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)))
```

I also tried to send the `Uri` this way:

```
val uri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + File.pathSeparator + File.separator + File.separator + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + filename)
```

but it doesn't work either. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 days of headaches i finally solved... what i've done was just save the image resource and then serve it:

```
val current = filePaths!![mViewPager!!.currentItem]

val imagePath = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "_temp")

if(!imagePath.exists())
   imagePath.mkdirs()

 val imageToShare = File(imagePath, "share.jpeg")

if(imageToShare.exists())
    imageToShare.delete()

 imageToShare.createNewFile()

 val out = FileOutputStream(imageToShare)
 val imageToSave = utils.createBitmap(current.resourceId)
 imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out)
 out.flush()
 out.close()

 val uri = Uri.fromFile(imageToShare)

 val shareIntent : Intent = Intent()
 shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
 shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
 shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg")
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)))
```

:)

Answer (score 2):

[The `Uri` passed via `EXTRA_STREAM` needs to be a `content` `Uri`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM). And while some apps supporting `ACTION_SNED` are more flexible, few will handle the almost-completely-unused `android.resource` scheme.

Implement a `ContentProvider` to serve your content, and use a `Uri` for that content in your `Intent`. Also, use a concrete MIME type in your `Intent` — this is *your* content, so you know what the MIME type is.

Comment: You'll see, on my application the images are stored in the 'raw' resource folder... I've search how to create a ContentProvider for resources but have no look... i'll try to store a file "copy" of the image localy and then serve that copy... Thanks a lot!

Comment: @charli3B: "i'll try to store a file "copy" of the image localy and then serve that copy" -- you can use `FileProvider` to serve the image then.